# Docker stack deploy not pulling images from private resgistry even when using --with-registry-auth

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am deploying container using docker stack and docker-compose file using the following command

```
docker stack deploy --with-registry-auth -c compose.yml app
```

The initial deployment is successful, but when I re-run the command, I get the following error for containers:

```
Updating service sparkful_nginx (id: <some_id>)
image <image_url> could not be accessed on a registry to record
its digest. Each node will access <image_url> independently,
possibly leading to different nodes running different
versions of the image.
```

PS: I am using GitHub registry.

Comment: was the issue sorted out? if yes, pls share the solution?

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to do docker login on each machine followed by

```
docker login -u username -p password registry.hub.Docker.com/myproject 
docker stack deploy -c Docker-swarm.yml test --with-registry-auth
```

as explained over here

> Ref: http://littlebigextra.com/installing-docker-images-private-repositories-docker-swarm/

**Update**
With Github Registry, it's a known issue open at the moment.
https://github.com/containerd/containerd/issues/3291#issuecomment-579804848

Comment: I am only using one machine and I am already logged in, else it won't even deploy on first run.

Comment: Looks like a known issue. https://github.com/containerd/containerd/issues/3291#issuecomment-579804848